# How can i find the current physical path where a custom windows service, resides?

Tags: .net, windows-services

i have installed my own custom Windows Service. I need to find out the physical path, where the service exists.

eg.

```
log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator.Configure(
    new System.IO.FileInfo(<insert path here> + "log4net.config"));
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location)
```

Comment: Nope - this isn't correct. It returns the location/path AND the exe name.... ????

Comment: How does that compare to my suggested answer? just another way but will also work?

Comment: Check MSDN: AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirector - Gets the base directory that the assembly resolver uses to probe for assemblies.
Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location - returns the path and name of currently executing assembly.

Answer (score 0):

<strike>System.Environment.CurrentDirectory?</strike>

Actually the above doesn't work but this does:

```
string servicePath = System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(
    System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location);
```

Comment: I think all services are started in %WINDIR%\system32

Comment: Sure, but once you get that, you can get the path using the GetDirectoryName static method o the Path class in System.IO.

Comment: Hmm. ok .. is that better than my suggested answer? or are they both the same thing .. ??